# How to access string using for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am having trouble appending the meeting name for each horse in the race. I think I am treating a list as a dictionary. How do you know the difference between a list and dictionary when reading JSON and how do I change my code so that it can append a list?

My code:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
links = []
request1 = requests.get('https://api.beta.tab.com.au/v1/recommendation-service/featured-events?jurisdiction=NSW')
json1 = request1.json()
for n in json1['nextToGoRaces']:
        links.append(n['_links']['self'])
tabntg2 = []
for l in links:
    request2 = requests.get(l)
    json2 = request2.json()
    for m in json2['meeting']:
        for r in json2['runners']:
            tabntg2.append((m['meetingName'], r['runnerName'], r['parimutuel']['returnWin']))
```

JSON:

```
   "raceNumber":7,
   "raceName":"JOCKEY CELEBRATION DAY SPRINT",
   "raceDistance":1000,
   "trackDirection":"anticlockwise",
   "meeting":{
      "meetingName":"BELMONT",
      "venueMnemonic":"BEL",
      "meetingDate":"2020-08-01",
      "location":"WA",
      "raceType":"R",
      "sellCode":{}
   },
   "skyRacing":{},
   "hasParimutuel":true,
   "hasFixedOdds":true,
   "broadcastChannel":null,
   "broadcastChannels":[],
   "hasForm":true,
   "hasEarlySpeedRatings":true,
   "allIn":false,
   "cashOutEligibility":"Disabled",
   "allowBundle":true,
   "willHaveFixedOdds":true,
   "fixedOddsOnlineBetting":true,
   "raceStartTime":"2020-08-01T08:00:00.000Z",
   "raceClassConditions":"MIN-84",
   "apprenticesCanClaim":false,
   "prizeMoney":"$100000.00",
   "raceStatus":"Normal",
   "substitute":"NR",
   "results":[],
   "pools":[],
   "allowMulti":true,
   "allowParimutuelPlace":true,
   "parimutuelPlaceStatus":"Open",
   "allowFixedOddsPlace":true,
   "numberOfPlaces":3,
   "numberOfFixedOddsPlaces":3,
   "runners":[
      {
         "runnerName":"FLOW",
```

Comment: When reading the JSON... List: `[]`, dict: `{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to loop over the meeting object keys. It is a single object

```
json2 = request2.json()
m = json2['meeting']
for r in json2['runners']:
    tabntg2.append((m['meetingName'], r['runnerName'], r['parimutuel']['returnWin']))
```